# Not able to export to csv all transfer events of a specific contract on Ethplorer.io

Tags: events, etherscan

I'm able to use the Export to csv function, but it's only giving me the most recent 1000 events. Any suggestions on how to get ALL (2100+) of the events in a csv file?

https://ethplorer.io/address/0x2c2391f793f4f81475d87fffe366458ce5380a13#

Answer (score 0):

Use [etherscan.ion](http://etherscan.io) instead.

Here's the link to the address you are looking for: https://etherscan.io/txs?a=0x2c2391f793f4f81475d87fffe366458ce5380a13

You can find all the transactions there - 4856 as of now. You can scrape all the transactions (if that's fine with etherscan.io), or checkout the [APIs they offer](https://etherscan.io/apis#logs).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide on how to export Ethereum data to csv https://medium.com/@medvedev1088/exporting-and-analyzing-ethereum-blockchain-f5353414a94e

It uses https://github.com/medvedev1088/ethereum-etl which outputs the data into `blocks.csv`, `transactions.csv`, `erc20_transfers.csv`.

`blocks.csv`

```
Column                  | Type               |
------------------------|---------------------
block_number            | bigint             |
block_hash              | hex_string         |
block_parent_hash       | hex_string         |
block_nonce             | hex_string         |
block_sha3_uncles       | hex_string         |
block_logs_bloom        | hex_string         |
block_transactions_root | hex_string         |
block_state_root        | hex_string         |
block_miner             | hex_string         |
block_difficulty        | bigint             |
block_total_difficulty  | bigint             |
block_size              | bigint             |
block_extra_data        | hex_string         |
block_gas_limit         | bigint             |
block_gas_used          | bigint             |
block_timestamp         | bigint             |
block_transaction_count | bigint             |
```

`transactions.csv`

```
Column              |    Type     |
--------------------|--------------
tx_hash             | hex_string  |
tx_nonce            | bigint      |
tx_block_hash       | hex_string  |
tx_block_number     | bigint      |
tx_index            | bigint      |
tx_from             | hex_string  |
tx_to               | hex_string  |
tx_value            | bigint      |
tx_gas              | bigint      |
tx_gas_price        | bigint      |
tx_input            | hex_string  |
```

`erc20_transfers.csv`

```
Column              |    Type     |
--------------------|--------------
erc20_token         | hex_string  |
erc20_from          | hex_string  |
erc20_to            | hex_string  |
erc20_value         | bigint      |
erc20_tx_hash       | hex_string  |
erc20_block_number  | bigint      |
```

Answer (score 0):

[BlockScout.com](https://blockscout.com/eth/mainnet) supplies an ability to export transactions on every address to CSV (up to 10k txs).

Take a look, for instance, at the bottom of the page https://blockscout.com/eth/mainnet/address/0x2c2391f793f4f81475d87fffe366458ce5380a13/transactions. *Download CSV* button is there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily using an Alchemy.com API key to access archival data through their nodes.

Set up a connection to their RPC using something like Ethers, here is a code demo:

```
const { AlchemyProvider } = require("@ethersproject/providers");
const { Contract } = require("@ethersproject/contracts");

// I'm just including the Transfer event in the ABI since that is all you want to query at the moment
const ABI = [
  {
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "internalType": "address",
        "name": "from",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "internalType": "address",
        "name": "to",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": false,
        "internalType": "uint256",
        "name": "tokenId",
        "type": "uint256"
      },
    ],
    "name": "Transfer",
    "type": "event"
  }
]

const demo =  async () => {
  let alchemyApiKey = 'YOUR_ALCHEMY_API_KEY'
  let tokenContractAddress = '0x2c2391f793f4f81475d87fffe366458ce5380a13';
  let provider = AlchemyProvider.getWebSocketProvider(null, alchemyApiKey) // you could also use "homestead" instead of null (it defaults to homestead/mainnet)
  let contract = await new Contract(tokenContractAddress, ABI, provider);
  let events = [];
  let blocksPerBatch = 100000; // I just picked this because it seemed like a reasonable batch size
  let lastCheckedBlock = 5668829; // could set this to zero but I looked at where the first tx was on Etherscan and just set it to the previous block so we don't check all the blocks before it where the contract didn't exist yet
  let latestBlockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
  let batchCount = Math.ceil(latestBlockNumber / blocksPerBatch);
  console.log({batchCount})
  for(let i = 0; i < batchCount; i++) {
    let toBlock = i === (batchCount - 1) ? latestBlockNumber : lastCheckedBlock + blocksPerBatch;
    let eventBatch = await contract.queryFilter('Transfer', lastCheckedBlock, toBlock);
    console.log(`Fetched ${eventBatch.length} events in batch #${i + 1}`);
    events = [...events, ...eventBatch];
    lastCheckedBlock = toBlock;
  }
  // At this point you should have all of the events
  console.log({events});
}

demo();
```